# Node > npm start > npm ERR

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm, package.json

I try to run this JS project on mac [this JS project](https://github.com/codebubb/job-search-app) but when i type `npm start` it made me a npm error :

[image]

I browsing any website to find a solution for my problem, although this i already put on my `package.json` a  `start": webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot` , `start": "node app.js"` or `start": "node index.html"`

**I type many combination like on terminal:**

`npm install npm@latest`

`npm install --global --verbose promised-io`

`npm run snyk-protect`

`npm cache clean --force`

**...but still no such changes were**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're in the root directory of that repository. The `package.json` however is in `frontend/` so you need to navigate there with `cd frontend`. Once in the correct directory `npm start` or `npm run build` should work.

Do make sure that you have run `npm install` first in that directory.